# Amazon RDS connection string setup

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, cloud, connection-string, amazon-rds

I have successfully created an Amazon RDS database, now I have also connected to this database in my ASP.Net application in Visual Studio. However, previously this database was stored locally, so now I am trying to migrate to the cloud (Amazon RDS).

How do I setup my connection string? In my `app.config` file, as you can see, previously it is set to the local database.

I am using the latest version of Entity Framework

```
    <add name="BookStoreEntityModelContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/BookStoreEntityModel.csdl|res://*/BookStoreEntityModel.ssdl|res://*/BookStoreEntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDb;Initial Catalog=BookStore;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

Comment: See how Data Source is pointing to `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDb`? Change that to the proper server name that your new cloud hosted DB server is at. You probably can't use integrated security any more either, so you'll probably want to set that to false and add user ID and Password and use SQL Auth. There may be better ways - I've never connected to a DB hosted in RDS before.

Comment: You should of posted this as the answer, because this worked! Thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer, this is what worked for me on .netCore 3.1 with EFCore, but the connection string should be interpreted the same for your case.

This is a truncated example of what we use for our RDS MSSQL server for connectionString value:

```
Server=tcp:example-endpoint-db.rds.amazonaws.com,1234; Initial Catalog=MyApp.DatabaseName; User=myappusername; Password=myapppassword; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; Application Name=MyApp.Api
```

The example-endpoint-db.rds.amazonaws.com and port can be derived from your RDS web console after your selected your DB as referenced:

[image]